# Polygon and Vertices count for Blender 2.9?

Tags: vertices, polycount

How can I find the polygon and vertices count for all the objects in the scene in Blender 2.9? It used to be on the bottom right corner, but in blender 2.9, its not there. Here is a screenshot. The top screenshot is Blender 2.83, and the bottom one is Blender 2.9.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check the *Statistics* box in the *Viewport Overlays* to get those counts back, though in a different location.

[image: Location of the viewport overlays menu -- top right dropdown by overlapping circles icon]

[image]

If you need to see them at the bottom right of the screen you can enable the information using *System > Preferences*, and in the *Interface* section enable the information you want to view as part of the *Status Bar*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Someone on the Blender Dev team must really not like that lower status bar. I seem to recall this information disappeared in the 2.80 tree for awhile, too.

Comment: Hello :). You can simply rightclick on the status bar and select which info to show.